# Blocking all ip addresses except one - Ubuntu server 16 - iptables

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have 2 routers. On the second router I want to block all the incoming traffic, only one server should have access to the internet.

[image]

My rules are as follows.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.0.57 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.57 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.57 -j ACCEPT
```

But it does not work. Computer 192. 168.0.57 does not have internet access.  Please any one can correct my rules.

Comment: Your rules are too restrictive. If you wish to connect to "the internet" you are going to have to allow more IP than 192.168.0.57 and more ports than port 22 and 80. When you connect to a web server you use port 80 on the server, but not port 80 on your client.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Add something like that`iptables -A FORWARD -m tcp -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 80,22,53 -j ACCEPT` ?

Comment: this documentation is a bit dated but see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo .to save use https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently#iptables-persistent_for_Debian.2FUbuntu for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iptables rule set does not have an `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` path through the `forward` chain:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. Should I add sudo `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT` ?